# General Network Error when connecting to SQL Server using WinCE Motorola devices

Tags: sql-server, networking, windows-ce, motorola

I get the Exception: "General network error. Check your network documentation." when connecting to our new SQL Server 2008 R2 server. Nothing more that that I can tell about the exception.

In windows CE5 or CE6 (depending if using Motorola MC3090 or MC3190), Microsoft SQL Client 2.0 is installed (package sql.wce5.armv4i.CAB get deployed when running the application from Visual Studio 2008). I’m not able to connect to that DB on both version of the gun… I’m only able to connect with our Windows applications (x32 and x64). The connection string I use is the following: "Data Source=ip_address;Database=dbname;User ID=username;Password=password"

I successfully connected to a dev database in our LAN. The dev database server is also 2008 R2 SP1 but there are no port block (wide open). Apparently, nothing is blocked according to the sys admins. The new DB server is now virtual and remote.

Is it possible there is some kind of options to prevent connections from some sources? Is there any diagnostics tools I can use?

Any ideas beside that?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a routing or name resolution problem.  Can the device see the remote machine at all (i.e. ping, web server, ftp, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was finally my fault. When testing I left the gun on the cradle and connection failed that way... I needed to test with the gun not on the cradle using its wireless connection and it worked!